# postgres pg_dump too many to exclude

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have schema let's say student and it has 300 tables and another schema employee which consists of 200 tables

The thing is in student schema I only need 20 tables and in employee I only need 15 tables to be backup

is there a way to use pg_dump without excluding all those tables, the script is too long if I type **`-n student -t table1, table2, etc..`**

Comment: Just include the tables that you need

Comment: 1) `-t table1`  is including the table not excluding, that would be `-T`. 2) If you are doing this with `pg_dump` you can do `-t pattern` to match multiple tables.  See [Patterns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PATTERNS) for more info.

Comment: "too long" for what?